# why if response is 200 I still parse error?

Tags: javascript

Hi I've got a parse error when I use javascript switch, ajax and php. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I'm not sure where the error could be, I've tested the php code without using ajax and it works fine but I'm wondering if I've missed something. I've also checked with the browser webmaster tool and I can see the status is 200

**This is my javascript code:**

```
$("#updateCertify").click(function (event) {

        event.preventDefault(event);

        var form = $('#updateCertify');

        $.ajax({

          url: form.action,
          type: form.method,
          data: $(form).serialize(),
          dataType: 'json',

        beforeSend: function() {
            $(".loader").show();
        },

        success: function(response) {

            $(".loader").hide();

            swal({
                    title: response.title,
                    text: response.message,
                    type: response.status
                },

                function() {
                    location.reload();
                }
            );
        },

        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {

            $(".loader").hide();

              if (jqXHR.status === 0) {

                  swal('Il server non risponde', 'Siamo spiacenti non è stato possibile eseguire questa operazione, per favore contatta l\'amministratore di sistema.', 'info');

              } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {

                  swal('Errore 404', 'Siamo spiacenti non è stato possibile eseguire questa operazione, per favore contatta l\'amministratore di sistema.', 'info');

              } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {

                  swal('Errore 500', 'Siamo spiacenti non è stato possibile eseguire questa operazione, per favore contatta l\'amministratore di sistema.', 'info');

              } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {

                  swal('Si è verificato un errore!', 'Siamo spiacenti non è stato possibile eseguire questa operazione, per favore contatta l\'amministratore di sistema.', 'info');

              } else if (exception === 'timeout') {

                  swal('Time Out', 'Siamo spiacenti non è stato possibile eseguire questa operazione, per favore contatta l\'amministratore di sistema.', 'info');

              } else if (exception === 'abort') {

                  swal('Richiesta Annullata', 'Siamo spiacenti non è stato possibile eseguire questa operazione, per favore contatta l\'amministratore di sistema.', 'info');

              } else {

                  swal('Errore non previsto', 'Siamo spiacenti non è stato possibile eseguire questa operazione, per favore contatta l\'amministratore di sistema.', 'info');
              }

          }

        });

});
```

**This is the php code:**

```
require_once('../../../config/connect.php');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $flat_id = $_POST['flatid'];

    $impianto_idraulico = isset($_POST['impianto_idraulico']) ? $_POST['impianto_idraulico'] : '0';
    $impianto_condizionamento = isset($_POST['impianto_condizionamento']) ? $_POST['impianto_condizionamento'] : '0';
    $impianto_gas = isset($_POST['impianto_gas']) ? $_POST['impianto_gas'] : '0';
    $impianto_ventilazione = isset($_POST['impianto_ventilazione']) ? $_POST['impianto_ventilazione'] : '0';
    $impianto_scarico = isset($_POST['impianto_scarico']) ? $_POST['impianto_scarico'] : '0';
    $impianto_elettrico = isset($_POST['impianto_elettrico']) ? $_POST['impianto_elettrico'] : '0';
    $impianto_telefonico = isset($_POST['impianto_telefonico']) ? $_POST['impianto_telefonico'] : '0';
    $impianto_sorveglianza = isset($_POST['impianto_sorveglianza']) ? $_POST['impianto_sorveglianza'] : '0';
    $impianto_antenna = isset($_POST['impianto_antenna']) ? $_POST['impianto_antenna'] : '0';

    $query_update_certification = mysqli_prepare($conn, "UPDATE km_flat_security SET km_flat_impianto_idraulico=?, km_flat_impianto_condizionamento=?, km_flat_impianto_gas=?, km_flat_impianto_ventilazione=?, km_flat_impianto_scarico=?, km_flat_impianto_elettrico=?, km_flat_impianto_telefonico=?, km_flat_impianto_sorveglianza=?, km_flat_impianto_antenna=? WHERE km_flat_flat_id=?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query_update_certification, 'iiiiiiiiii', $impianto_idraulico, $impianto_condizionamento, $impianto_gas, $impianto_ventilazione, $impianto_scarico, $impianto_elettrico, $impianto_telefonico, $impianto_sorveglianza, $impianto_antenna, $flat_id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($query_update_certification);
    mysqli_stmt_close($query_update_certification);

    // Passo messaggio di risposta se l'operazione è andata a buon fine
    $response['title']  = 'Operazione eseguita con successo!';
    $response['message'] = 'Certificazioni immobile aggiornate con successo';
    $response['status']  = 'success';

    echo json_encode($response);

}else{

  header('Location: ' . BASE_URL . '/404.php');
  exit();

}
```

**This is the error from webmaster tool**

```
abort: function abort()
always: function always()
complete: function add()
done: function add()
error: function add()
fail: function add()
getAllResponseHeaders: function getAllResponseHeaders()
getResponseHeader: function getResponseHeader()
overrideMimeType: function overrideMimeType()
pipe: function then()
progress: function add()
promise: function promise()
readyState: 4
responseText: "<html lang=\"it\">\n\n    <head>\n        <meta charset=\"utf-8\" />\n        <title>Kondo Manager | Flat details</title>\n        <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\">\n        <meta content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\" name=\"viewport\" />\n        <meta content=\"Pagina per l'amministrazione degli immobili\" />\n        <meta content=\"Karibusana\" name=\"author\" />\n        <link href=\"//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700&subset=all\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />\n        <link href=\"../../layout/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />\n        <link href=\"../../layout/assets/global/plugins/simple-line-icons/simple-line-icons.min.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />\n        <link href=\"../../layout/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />\n        <link href=\"../../layout/assets/global/css/components-rounded.min.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" id=\"styl…"
setRequestHeader: function setRequestHeader()
state: function state()
status: 200
statusCode: function statusCode()
statusText: "OK"
success: function add()
then: function then()
__proto__: {…}
__defineGetter__: function __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: function __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: function __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: function __lookupSetter__()
constructor: function Object()
hasOwnProperty: function hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: function isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: function propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: function toLocaleString()
toSource: function toSource()
toString: function toString()
unwatch: function unwatch()
valueOf: function valueOf()
watch: function watch()
```

Comment: Let's look at the very first line after the event 'click'. Try to minimize it as `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: @WebDegBrian I doubt the unnecessary parameter would cause the described problem.

Comment: Are you talking about the `event.preventDefault()` ? I do think so, and try to minimize it as possible

Comment: @pippo Use the browser developer tools to look at the actual response text returned. Your error is probably that there's something wrong with the JSON.

Comment: `require_once('../../../config/connect.php');` jesus christ try adding a base_url or something there boy

Comment: @WebDegBrian yes; it's already there in the code. Passing the `event` parameter is unnecessary but it probably won't hurt anything. The OP describes an HTTP request that succeeds but which is followed by a "parse error".

Comment: OP it would also help if you'd post the exact error that you're getting. The fact that you get a 200 means that as far as the HTTP request is concerned, everything worked; however that 200 does not guarantee that the response can be parsed as JSON.

Comment: @Pointy but just to minimize it for later uses.

Comment: Hi, i've edited the post, i've added what i see from webmaster tool

Comment: Hi @Phiter thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All sorted

```
 $(function() {

    $("#updateCertifyForm").on("submit", function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: "../controllers/ctrl_admin_flat_app/ctrl_admin_update_flat_certifications.php",
            type: "post",
            data: $(this).serialize(),

            beforeSend: function() {
              $(".loader").show();
            },

            success: function(response) {

              $(".loader").hide();

              swal({
                      title: response.title,
                      text: response.message,
                      type: response.status
                  });

            },

            error: function(jqXHR, exception) {

                $(".loader").hide();

                  if (jqXHR.status === 0) {

                      swal('Il server non risponde', 'Siamo spiacenti non è stato possibile eseguire questa operazione, per favore contatta l\'amministratore di sistema.', 'info');

                  } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {

                      swal('Errore 404', 'Siamo spiacenti non è stato possibile eseguire questa operazione, per favore contatta l\'amministratore di sistema.', 'info');

                  } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {

                      swal('Errore 500', 'Siamo spiacenti non è stato possibile eseguire questa operazione, per favore contatta l\'amministratore di sistema.', 'info');

                  } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {

                      swal('Si è verificato un errore!', 'Siamo spiacenti non è stato possibile eseguire questa operazione, per favore contatta l\'amministratore di sistema.', 'info');

                  } else if (exception === 'timeout') {

                      swal('Time Out', 'Siamo spiacenti non è stato possibile eseguire questa operazione, per favore contatta l\'amministratore di sistema.', 'info');

                  } else if (exception === 'abort') {

                      swal('Richiesta Annullata', 'Siamo spiacenti non è stato possibile eseguire questa operazione, per favore contatta l\'amministratore di sistema.', 'info');

                  } else {

                      swal('Errore non previsto', 'Siamo spiacenti non è stato possibile eseguire questa operazione, per favore contatta l\'amministratore di sistema.', 'info');
                  }

            }

        });
    });

  });
```